While True loop stuck at a certain iteration while trying to optimize for the best curve fit given a data set in python
So basically I wanted to make my own function to fit a curve given a dataset. I generally applied the least square method for the types polynomial, exponential and logarithmic but I noticed that this method is not that good on its own for fitting a curve on exponential data sets. I did the same curve fit with scipy and it gave a much better result. Because of that I decided to use the trial and error method of curve fitting, with initial estimates of a and b given by the least square method. I encountered a new problem. The time for the loop to spit out an error given a trial in each iteration gradually decreased and at some point the loop was just stuck at one place.
The code I have right now:
def exp_func(x,i,a,b):
    return a*np.exp(b*x[i])

def error_function(x,y,i,a,b):
    approximation = exp_func(x,i,a,b)
    residual = (abs(y[i]-approximation))/y[i]
    return residual

...
...
def curve_fit(data,x,type,degree=None):  
     if type == 'exp':
          A = np.ones((len(data),2))
          for i in range(0,len(data)):
             A[i,1] = x[i]
          data = np.log(data)
          data = np.transpose(data)
          y = np.linalg.inv(np.transpose(A)@A)@(np.transpose(A)@data)
          y[0] = np.exp(y[0])
          data = np.exp(data)
          data = np.transpose(data)
          learning_rate = 1
          tolerance = 0.5
          previous_error = (sum(error_function(x,data,i,y[0],y[1]) for i in range(0,len(data))))
          new_error = (sum(error_function(x,data,i,y[0],y[1]) for i in range(0,len(data))))
          while True:
              if new_error < tolerance:
                  break
              y_0new = y[0] + learning_rate*(np.random.uniform(-1,1))
              y_1new = y[1] + learning_rate*(np.random.uniform(-1,1))
              new_error =  (sum(error_function(x,data,i,y_0new,y_1new) for i in range(0,len(data))))
              if new_error < previous_error:
                  y[0] = y_0new
                  y[1] = y_1new
                  previous_error = new_error
          return y

x = np.linspace(0,5,20) #Testing it out
test1 = np.array([1,10,25,40,50])
t1 = np.arange(1,6)
a,b = cf.curve_fit(test1,t1,'exp')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.grid()
plt.plot(t1,test1,marker='o',ms=5,linestyle='')
plt.plot(x,a*np.exp(b*x),color='black')
plt.show()

I assume you don't require the code for the other types of curves.

Include sample input data and graphs. Trial and error is not crazy when applied manually, but is unlikely to work in an unsupervised manner.

@Reinderien I did try it out with a simple data set, do you want me to add that in the code provided above? Also I want to do the curve fitting automatically so if not trial and error, what do you recommend?

Welcome to SO, please write a [mcve], read [ask] and update your post accordingly.
